# Error: Content area not found, <?php the_content() ?>

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am creating a wordpress site with elementor page builder, i got the error above, how can i insert `the_content()` function in my template

I saw the code on wordpress doc, the problem is, i dont know where to put the php function

Answer (score 1):

Got this error as a result of new wordpress editor *glutenberg*

I will highlight best practices on how to resolve this issue

1. Create a child theme for your theme: this is important because we will be making changes to the file and we will lose changes after updating the theme.
   To create a child theme the easy way, just install Child theme generator as a plugin on your wordpress site.
2. Activate your child theme.
3. Go to the root of your new child theme and create a new file (page.php)
4. Go to mother theme(previous theme) and copy codesn from page.php
5. Paste the code in your new page.php child theme.
6. copy this code `<?php the_content() ?>` and paste it in your new page.php

save and refresh your wordpress page..

Lemme know if i have been able to save a life.